# Can't get "check host" to work with monit / Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, monit

I'm a noob to monit, and I am having trouble following the examples and getting things running on a server running Ubuntu 16.04. Specifically, I am trying to add a "check host" line in the following format:

```
check host <subdomain.domain.com> with address <subdomain.domain.com>
  if failed port 80 protocol http 
  and request <page-name>
  with timeout 5 seconds
  then exec <command>
```

This syntax is similar to that found here (see "check host ftp.redhat.com"):
https://linux.die.net/man/1/monit

However, I'm getting a strange error:

```
There is no service named "subdomain.domain.com"
```

This error makes no sense based on what the docs say, since I'm trying to check a remote http address, not check a service. I'm unsure how to proceed.

For some context, I wrote a microserver in Golang, getting requests forward from port 80 via nginx. This process is getting millions of http requests a day.

Because it is possible for the process to crash without dying, I believe the easiest way to check if it's running is to hit the actual public URL and make sure it's responding--when it crashes I start getting 502 errors. I simply want to restart the process if it goes down. I mention this, because I am primarily a developer, not a server admin, and if there is a better way to ensure the golang microserver is still running properly, I'd be interested in knowing about it.

Comment: That's an interesting question, since I do use Monit for monitoring services, but didn't know it can "check hosts" as well. If that works fine, then it could be a light weight replacement for Nagios/Icinga. After some searching I found an example here : http://debianhelp.co.uk/monit.htm The part with " #Check host for which services up/down on particular port." Could you have a look and try the similar syntax used there ? Mean while I might test it myself as well, given time. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check your monit version, if installed via apt-get (on 16.04) should be 5.16 the docs are (as of today) for 5.24.
You can check changelog here: https://mmonit.com/monit/changes/

If you like to install current version here is a good tutorial: https://guides.wp-bullet.com/install-latest-monit-ubuntu-16-04-later/

Otherwise here is a monit-script wich works on older versions (even for 5.6 = Ubuntu 14.04):

```
check host example.com with address example.com
  if failed
    url https://example.com
    timeout 10 seconds
    for 3 cycles 
  then alert
```